# Invalid date showing in firefox but not in chrome - ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using below code in `home.html`:

```
{{this.myDate | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}
```

It is running in chrome but it is displaying an error in firefox.
Please see below image:

[image]

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: unable to find polyfills.ts  , there are so many polyfills.js  , confused which one to copy, its huge code

Comment: what is the `value` of `this.myDate`? Refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_date

Comment: this is ionic and there is no such file

Comment: will tis solve the purpose ?